# I want to enable one picklist value for another picklist value

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a existing vf page where I have two picklist field and I want to enable one picklist for another.For example

Picklist Exp__c
A
B
C
Picklist  Exp2__c
XX
YY
So if the value A is selected from picklist Exp__c then picklist Exp2__c both the value should enable and mandatory.For value B and C picklist EXP2__c sholud not appear.I want to do this in a visual force page.Please help with vf page and class.

Comment: did you have any code yet? A lot of guys here can help you, but not do your work instead of it. Basic idea - read how to make edit page and use apex:selectList together with outputPanel and rerender on change

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me as though you only want to show Exp2__c if Exp__c has value A?

You can do this pretty easily with jQuery. You'll first want to get the values of Exp__c and Exp2__c. You can do this a couple of different ways, but personally I prefer to do it this way. Firstly, in Apex you'll want to get the values of the picklist:

```
public List<String> exp {
  get {
    if (exp == null) {
      exp = new List<String>();
      Schema.DescribeFieldResult field = Custom_Object__c.Exp__c.getDescribe();

      for (Schema.PicklistEntry f : field.getPicklistValues())
        exp.add(f.getLabel());
    }

    return exp;
  }
  set;
}
```

All this will do is get the list of picklist values and add them to the `List<String> exp`.

You can then display the list in Visualforce like so, using `<apex:repeat>`.

```
<select id="exp">
  <option value=""></option>
  <apex:repeat value="{!exp}" var="e">
    <option value="{!e}">{!e}</option>
  </apex:repeat>
</select>
```

You'd want to do the same for the second picklist, only now you can use jQuery on the two Ids. For instance:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#exp2").hide();

  $("#exp").change(function() {
    if ($("#exp").val() == 'A') {
      $("#exp2").show();
    }
    else {
      $("#exp2").hide(); 
    }
  })
});
```

This will show and hide the picklists. Finally, to make `exp2` required, you could use another bit of jQuery to control that inside of the Visualforce page.

Assuming you have a button like so:

```
<button type="button">
  Do something!
</button>
```

You could have a bit of jQuery like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#performAction').click(function(e) {
    if ($("#exp").val() == 'A' && ("#exp2").val() == '') {
      e.preventDefault();
      alert("Exp2 is a required value!");
    }
  });
});
```

This should stop the page from doing anything and display and alert telling the user they need to enter a value in Exp2.